# An algorithm for two farmer collect apple problem

Tags: c, algorithm

I am solving this problem recently:

> In a vast orchard, you find yourself amidst m rows and n columns of
> apple trees, each tree bearing a certain number of ripe apples denoted
> by a matrix grid. This matrix, with dimensions m × n, represents your
> field of apples, where `grid[i][j]` signifies the number of apples you
> can collect from the tree at position (i, j).
>
> To assist you in apple-picking, you have two dedicated fruit farmers:
>
> - Fruit Farmer 1, stationed at the top-left corner (0, 0)
> - Fruit Farmer 2, stationed at the top-right corner (0, n - 1)
> - Your goal is to devise a plan that maximizes the total number of apples collected by both farmers
>
> Print the maximum number of apples that can be collected by these two
> diligent fruit farmers by following the rules below:
>
> - From any cell (i, j), the farmers can move to one of the following neighboring cells in the next row: lower left(i + 1, j - 1), downward(i + 1, j), or lower right(i + 1, j + 1)
> - Whenever a farmer passes through a cell, they promptly gather all the apples from that tree, and the tree is left empty
> - In the event that both farmers happen to land on the same cell, they must share the apples, but only one farmer can collect them
> - The farmers are not allowed to venture outside the orchard’s boundaries at any point
> - Both farmers must reach the bottom row of the orchard to complete their applepicking mission

I have problem to figure out how two farmers interact. How can I solve the question?

I came up with using dynamic programming to solve every grid max harvest for one farmer. But I don't know how to solve the problem.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 100
#define MAX_COLS 100

int main() {
    int m = 3;
    int n = 3;
    //example
    int grid[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = {
        {3, 1, 1},
        {5, 6, 2},
        {9, 6, 7}
    };

    int dp[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = { 0 };

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        dp[m - 1][j] = grid[m - 1][j];
    }
    
    for (int i = m - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = grid[i][j] + dp[i + 1][j];
            if (j > 0) {
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], grid[i][j] + dp[i + 1][j - 1]);
            }
            if (j < n - 1) {
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], grid[i][j] + dp[i + 1][j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
  
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ",dp[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outcome:

```
18 16 16
14 15 9
9 6 7
```

Comment: Re “Should I create another array to memorize the path or are there better solutions?”: Without any definition of “better,” this is only a subjective question and does not have a good objective answer. Better could be faster to compute, simpler code, less memory, or other factors. Are you being graded on how good your solution for “memorizing” the path is? Do you even need to memorize the path to find the solution to the stated problem? Why is this your concern rather than finding the optimal solution? Is the code you show otherwise finished, that is, does it solve the stated problem?

Comment: Maybe count apples separately for each farmer? `int dp[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS][2] = { 0 };`

Comment: Aside: you shouldn't really have an array of that size on the stack. If you are using 'dynamic programming' then use 'dynamic memory allocation'.

Comment: This is interesting; are the two independent in a way that will permit solving each in series, or will the optimum sometimes only be attained if you consider both in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear that the farmers must takes about the same number of turns, so let us assume at each iterations we have up to 6 options: Farmer1 moves down_left, down, down right and likewise for farmer 2.

The count may be less than 6 as the farmer is at an edge or bottom.

Note there are no loops.  Each farmer will eventually make `MAX_ROWS-1` move down.

A solution involves recursion.

Consider the *state*:

- `int grid[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS]`
- `int farmer_row[2]; int farmer_col[2]`
- `int move_count`  (initially 0)
- `int move[(MAX_ROWS - 1) * 2]` to record which of the 6 moves made.  (no need to initialize)
- Apple sum count
- Best apple sum count
- Best move list.

1. Initialize the state
2. Call a recursive `function(state)`.

A. Attempt each of the 6 moves keeping track if at least one was legal.

B. For each move: Make a move and record the best possible move, (most apple sum - return value from recursion).  A return value of -1 indicates the recursion failed to achieve a legal end state.

C. If at the last move and the apple sum better than the best apple sum, copy the sum and move list to the best.

D. For each move: Undo the effects of the move.

E. If no legal move found return -1, else return the best sum.

3. Report the best sum and move list.

---

More advanced methods will pre-calculate the sum of the 2 highest trees per row and use that when examining the 6 possible moves and the current sum.  If the current sum + the best 2 of the remaining rows, per farmer, is less than a prior moves sum, no need to recurse on that move.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it could be to consider both positions at the same time.

Python code:

```py
def valid(l, r, n):
  return 0 <= l < n and 0 <= r < n and l <= r


def moves(l, r, n):
  candidates = [
    (l, r - 1),
    (l, r),
    (l, r + 1),
    (l - 1, r - 1),
    (l - 1, r),
    (l - 1, r + 1),
    (l + 1, r - 1),
    (l + 1, r),
    (l + 1, r + 1)
  ]
  return filter(lambda lr: valid(lr[0], lr[1], n), candidates)
    

def f(grid):
  m = len(grid)
  n = len(grid[0])
  dp = {
    (0, 0): grid[0][0] + grid[0][n-1]
  }
  for row in range(1, m):
    dp2 = {}
    for (l, r) in dp:
      for (ll, rr) in moves(l, r, n):
        count = grid[row][ll] + (
          grid[row][rr] if rr != ll else 0)
        new_total = dp[(l, r)] + count 
        if (ll, rr) in dp2:
          dp2[(ll, rr)] = max(
            dp2[(ll, rr)], new_total)
        else:
          dp2[(ll, rr)] = new_total
    dp = dp2
  return max(dp.values())

grid = [
  [3, 1, 1],
  [5, 6, 2],
  [9, 6, 7]
]

print(f(grid)) # 31
```